# what is the purpose of the additional resistors and capacitors in the reference design of the multiple feedback fully differential low pass filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-pass, active-filter

What is the purpose of the additional resistors and capacitors added  C14  R12  R14 R13  R15   C15 in the reference design of the .second order multiple feedback fully differential low pass filter?

When I enter the same parameters in Filterpro, I see these values,

[image]

and then when I enter the normalization value with 1k, this classic filter appears.

[image]

However, in the reference design, additionally C14 R12 R14 R13 R15 C15 was used.
[image]
What exactly is their purpose? I want to design a second order multiple feedback fully differential low pass filter with a gain of 1. What difference does it make if I add these values externally or not?
The differential filter output goes to an ADC input with a differential input.